# The property or field specification is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, marshalling

I get the exception

> The property or field specification is annotated to be transient so
>   can not be included in the proporder annotation.

When trying to specify a proporder for a bean I'm working with.  I have nothing annotated transient, so I'm unsure as to why this exception rears its ugly head at runtime.  If I remove the proporder, I don't get the exception but then when printing XML, I lose the "specification" field and the order is obviously wrong.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

This is the class I'm working with:

**EndpointBean**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "endpoint")
@XmlType (propOrder={"specification", "url", "changeset", "type", "formats"})
public class EndpointBean {

    private String specification;
    private String url;
    private String changeset;
    private String type;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "formats")
    @XmlElement(name = "format")
    private ArrayList<String> formats;

    public String getSpecification() {
        return specification;
    }

    public void setSpefification(String spefification) {
        this.specification = spefification;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getChangeset() {
        return changeset;
    }

    public void setChangeset(String changeset) {
        this.changeset = changeset;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFormats() {
        return formats;
    }

    public void setFormats(ArrayList<String> format) {
        this.formats = format;
    }   

}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: The property or field specification is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The property or field specification is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at conversion.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-50009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The property or field specification is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.transientInProporder(JAXBException.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.finalizeProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClassesAndProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1017)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you have a get/set mismatch.  Since in the code you have posted there is no `setSpecification` method the property is treated internally as if it were mapped with `@XmlTransient`.

What you currently have:

```java
public void setSpefification(String spefification) {
    this.specification = spefification;
}
```

What you need to change the setter to, to match the getter:

```java
public void setSpecification(String spefification) {
    this.specification = spefification;
}
```

Comment: Blaise, you are a god amongst men.  Can't believe I missed a typo that blatant.  Thanks for the explanation of that exception though, I didn't know that it would treat the property as transient, in that case.

Comment: @Prmths - I'm happy I could help.  JAXB will ignore getters without matching setters, if you annotate a get only property with `@XmlElement` it will be included when you marshal the object to XML.